# My local master does not contain changes from my completed pull request

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, git-bash

I have a project in Visual Studio 2019 that I cloned from an empty DevOps project. It is using git. I have created a local branch in Visual Studio from `master` and added a new solution. I have then committed the changes, synced with the server and pushed the commit. On DevOps I created a new pull request to merge my branch into master, then approved and completed the pull request.

When I checkout master in Visual Studio and pull, it updates to the latest commit. However, I do not see the Solution in the Solution Explorer (it is empty). I pull again and it says I'm up to date.

I have tried merging from `remotes/origin/master` also to no success. I have tried fetching `remotes/origin/master` no dice. I have tried deleting `master` and recreating it using so that it tracks `remotes/origin/master` with: `$ git branch -d master` and `$ git checkout -t remotes/origin/master` and still no joy.

Thank you for reading my query. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Closing and re-opening Visual Studio fixed this issue for me.

I have subsequently created a new local branch from master, made some changes, pushed them, submitted and completed the pull request, and now checking out master and pulling DOES show my changes.

Not sure why it wasn't working before but my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same when the Azure/Git credentials are expired or the domain password is expired.
In fact, there is a bug in VS 2019 (16.11.2 my version): no error displayed if VS failed to obtain auth. token during the pull operation.